# how can i detect a click on <iframe> in ionic 2

Tags: events, iframe, ionic2, click

I am using ionic 2. I am using the '**iframe'** tag to stream video but can't swipe the '**iframe**' .I just want to know how a click event can be caught when clicking inside the '**iframe**'.

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: thanking you for  noticing my mistake  and kindly reverting back to me @buhtz